# JavaScript Text Color Change To Each Word In Array

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, replace, highlight

I have this JavaScript Code:

```
            $(function() {
            var text = $(this).find("#text").html();

            var key_words = ['university', 'students', 'institutions', 'education'];

            function colorText(text, keywords) {
                var rd;
                $.each(keywords, function(index, item) {
                    var r = new RegExp(item, "gi")
                    rd = text.replace(r, '<span style="background: yellow">' + item + '</span>');
                });
                return rd;
            }


           var colorWords = colorText(text, key_words);

           $(this).find("#text").html(colorWords);

        });
```

I want to replace all key_words array with colors simple and easy. But always colored only students in whole text and thats all.

What i'm i doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you having?  It would help if you phrased your question in the form of, "I want my code to do X but when I run it, it does Y instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing it without a loop, would be:

```
 function colorText(text, keywords) {
     var regex = new RegExp(keywords.join('|'), 'gi');
     return text.replace(regex, '<span style="background: yellow">$&</span>');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks about great answers guys i really appreciate. But if i have captalize word like Students and student they wont be found in text. How could this be done ? The flag "i" in regEx replace all my Uppercase words with lowercase ;/ keyword: student text: Student captalize Student must be colored too. Which is the correct way to be maked?

Comment: This function will preserve the uppercase/lowercase. The `i` only means that it will find all instances regardless of upper/lowercase. The `$&` refers to the exact match found, it does not alter it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `colorText` function, you are resetting a variable `rd` every time you loop so it will only show the last item. Instead, try just updating the `text` value and returning it when you're finished, like this:

```
function colorText(text, keywords) {
    $.each(keywords, function (index, item) {
        var r = new RegExp(item, "gi")
        text = text.replace(r, '<span style="background: yellow">' + item + '</span>');
    });
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot about your answer (bow) it helped me.