# Change font color for each word in a string (JS or PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, colors

I've searched but cannot find a solution to increment the font color (eg. lightness +10%) for each of 3 or 4 words in a title. The font color will be initially set in SCSS with a color var.

**Example Title:**

> Here Is My New Title

In this example, lets say the title was 'dark blue'.. the words would be:

```
Here = darker blue
Is = navy blue
My = medium blue
New Title = light blue
```

There is a similar post here: [JavaScript Text Color Change To Each Word In Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545318/javascript-text-color-change-to-each-word-in-array) but this is searching for keywords in an array, not each word of a string.

I've also come across basic CSS/HTML only solutions like this, which won't work: [HTML: Changing colors of specific words in a string of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622808/html-changing-colors-of-specific-words-in-a-string-of-text)

**NOTE:**
I will be returning the title (string) in a php variable - in case there is a solution in PHP.

**GOAL:** I need to increment the font color (or even wrap consecutive words in spans and increment the SCSS var) for each word in a string.. open to suggestions.

**UPDATE**
I've added a jsfiddle link (http://jsfiddle.net/revive/xyy04u7d/) to show the JS implementation, thanks to Tushar, with some changes to include ampersands in the regex.

Here is the **PHP implementation**:

```
<?php
    $title = "SIMPLE TITLE & WITHOUT COLORS";
    $words   = preg_split('/\s+(?!&)/', $title);
?> 
<h3 class="colors blue">
<?php foreach($words as $word):?>
    <span><?php echo $word; ?></span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</h3>
```

Comment: if you know jquery you can do some dom tweaking by using it

Comment: For anyone else that would like to see how this solution played out.. I've created a JSFIDDLE here: http://jsfiddle.net/revive/xyy04u7d/ which adds to what Tushar provided and negates the & from the regex (I needed that on the same line as the word before it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the each word in separate `span` or any other element and then can be styled differently using the CSS `nth-child` property.

Using this approach, you don't have to create separate classes, and it'll work for any number of words in string.

```js
var str = 'Split the Text by one or more spaces. Join them to make them wrap in span elements. Then use CSS nthChild Properties :)';

str = '<span>' + str.split(/\s+/).join('</span> <span>') + '</span>';

$(document.body).append(str);
```

```css
span:nth-child(4n) {
  color: red;
}
span:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  color: green;
}
span:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  color: blue;
}
span:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

You can also use regex as follow:

```js
$("h1").html(function(i, oldHtml) {
  return oldHtml.replace(/(\S+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

```css
span:nth-child(4n) {
  color: red;
}
span:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  color: green;
}
span:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  color: blue;
}
span:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Hello World! Have a Great Day! </h1>
```

Comment: If you want PHP solution, you can use similar approach in PHP

Comment: Excellent.. thanks for such a simple solution.. and yes, might even refactor this to PHP .. but, the JS version works great. Thanks again.

Comment: @revive Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo that splits the words based on spaces, wraps each word in a span with a class name. You can style the elements however you like using the class name.

```js
var str = "Here Is My New Title which may well be way too longer than I have actually provided";
var res = "";

str.split(/\s+/).forEach(function(str, idx) {
  //Would only work with the string in question
  //res += "<span class='color-"+(idx+1)+"'>" + str + " </span>";
  //Would work with any amount of words in a string, applying the same set of classes every 5 words.
  res += "<span class='color-" + (idx % 5) + "'>" + str + " </span>";
});

$("body").append(res);
```

```css
.color-0 {
  color: violet;
}
.color-1 {
  color: indigo;
}
.color-2 {
  color: blue;
}
.color-3 {
  color: green;
}
.color-4 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is similar answer

change perticular text

```
first = str.substring(0,till);
    second = str.substring(till,last);
    //Print data
    $(this).html("<span style=color:"+setting.color+">"+first+"</span>"+ second);
```

Download Plugin : [string_color](https://github.com/hidaytrahman/hrStringColor)